# Summing ${\frac{1}{n^2}}$ over subsets of $N$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Are there $2$ subsets, say, $A$ and $B$, of the naturals such that
$$\sum_{n\in A}   f(n)   =  \sum_{n\in B}   f(n)$$

where $f(n)={\frac{1}{n^2}}$?

If $f(n)=\frac{1}{n}$ then there are many counterexamples, which is probably a consequence of the fact that the harmonic series diverges:
$$\frac23 = \frac12 + \frac16 = \frac14+\frac13+\frac1{12}$$
And if $f(n)=b^{-n}$ for some base $b$ then it is true because for all $M$, $\sum_{n>M} f(n) < f(M)$. (This is just the base-b representation of a real number.The case $b=2$ gives a <s>bijection</s> surjection $2^{N} \to [0,1])$.

So we have sort of an in-between case here.
Also, what if $A$,$B$:
-are required to be finite sets?
-are required to be infinite and disjoint?

Comment: The reason there are a lot of counterexamples for 1/n has little to do with the fact that the harmonic series diverges; it's just that frequently one can find two fractions of this form whose sum is also of this form.

Comment: Also, binary representation does not give a bijection from 2^N to [0, 1]; the map is surjective but not injective.

Comment: http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=152

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes to both cases:
1) $\frac{1}{15^2}+\frac{1}{20^2}=\frac{1}{12^2}$
2) $\frac{1}{15^2}+\frac{1}{150^2}+\frac{1}{1500^2}+...+\frac{1}{20^2}+\frac{1}{200^2}+\frac{1}{2000^2}+...=\frac{1}{12^2}+\frac{1}{120^2}+\frac{1}{1200^2}...$

for first case - if we have pythagorean triple (a,b,c), such that $a^2+b^2=c^2$, then:
$\frac{1}{a^2 b^2}=\frac{1}{a^2 c^2}+\frac{1}{b^2 c^2}$

Answer (score 1):

If two disjoint sets of naturals $A$ and $B$
satisfy
$\sum_{n \in A} n^2 = \sum_{n \in B} n^2$,
then, if $m = \prod_{n\in A} n \prod_{n \in B} n$,
$\sum_{n \in A} (n/m)^2 = \sum_{n \in B} (n/m)^2$
and each of the $n/m$ is the reciprocal of an integer
since $n|m$.

This extends directly to higher powers (via copy and paste):

If two disjoint sets of naturals $A$ and $B$
satisfy
$\sum_{n \in A} n^k = \sum_{n \in B} n^k$ 
for a positive integer $k$,
then, if $m = \prod_{n\in A} n \prod_{n \in B} n$,
$\sum_{n \in A} (n/m)^k = \sum_{n \in B} (n/m)^k$
and each of the $n/m$ is the reciprocal of an integer
since $n|m$.